# bind backslash to a non-standard keyboard key

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts, xfce, keyboard-layout

I am using a swiss apple keyboard at the moment. This keyboard requires some unreasonable finger acrobatics to type a backslash (shift+right alt+7). I'd like to bind the backslash to another key combination, specifically shift+4, which right now produces a "ç" which I never need.

I use Linux mint xcfe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For permanent solution issue command in console:

`echo 'keycode  13 = 4 backslash 4 ccedilla onequarter dollar onequarter' >> $HOME/.Xmodmap`

then switch layout or issue `xmodmap - < $HOME/.Xmodmap`

For a one time (or to be executed at each startup from `$HOME/.xinitrc`):
`xmodmap -e 'keycode  13 = 4 backslash 4 ccedilla onequarter dollar onequarter'`

Comment: Did you forget to remove the initial 4?

Comment: Nope, that's needed: otherwise you would get a `\` on pressing the 4 key alone.

Comment: In that case, I don't understand the syntax. `xmodmap -e 'keycode 79 = 4 backslash'` gives my the digit 4 for the numpad key "7" (= 79; got that from `xev`), dropping the `backslash` gives the same result; `xmodmap -e 'keycode 79 = backslash'` on the other hand gives me a backslash for the same key. This seems straightforward, but apparently not so?